# Jest fails with "Cannot use import statement outside a module" when running tests on a folder, but not on specific files

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm currently working on a Node.js project using ES6 modules, Jest for testing, and Babel for transpiling. My package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=production && node src/index.js",
    "dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && nodemon src/index.js",
    "test": "jest --no-cache",
    "coverage": "jest --coverage --no-cache",
    "lint": "eslint . --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.7",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.1",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
     ...
  }
}
```

The test that I'm running is:

```
import { getGPSCoords } from "../index.js";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

jest.mock("node-fetch", () => jest.fn());

describe("utils/get-gps-coords", () => {
  it("should return GPS coordinates when valid address is provided", async () => {
    const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve({
      features: [
        {
          geometry: {
            coordinates: [123, 456],
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    const mockFetchPromise = Promise.resolve({
      ok: true,
      json: () => mockJsonPromise,
    });
    fetch.mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);

    const result = await getGPSCoords("5 dummy street", "Dummy Town");

    expect(result).toEqual({
      longitude: 123,
      latitude: 456,
    });
  });
});
```

However, I'm encountering an error when running the `jest src/utils/` command or the test command in my package.json file. The error is:

> Test suite failed to run
>
> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
>
> Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
>
> By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
>
> Here's what you can do:
> If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
> If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
> To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
> If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
> If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
>
> You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
> For information about custom transformations, see:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation
>
> Details:
>
> /home/me/Desktop/App/server/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:9
> import http from 'node:http';
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>
> 1 | import fetch from "node-fetch";
> | ^
> 2 |
> 3 | async function getGPSCoords(address, zip, city) {
> 4 |   let url;
>
> at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../../../../usr/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
> at Object.require (src/utils/get-gps-coords/get-gps-coords.js:1:1)
> at Object.require (src/utils/index.js:5:1)
> at Object.require (src/utils/generate-token/generate-token.test.js:2:1)

Yet, when I test this specific file with `jest src/utils/get-gps-coords/get-gps-coords.test.js`, the test passes without any issues. Moreover, when I try to test another utility that doesn't import node-fetch, such as `jest src/utils/generate-token/generate-token.test.js`, it keeps throwing the same error as above.

My .babelrc configuration file is:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
  ]
}
```

I haven't any Jest config and I also have Jest installed globally.

I tried to use transformIgnorePatterns like said in the error but it didn't change anything.

```
"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!(node-fetch)/)"
    ]
  },
```

I also tried to use experimental ES6 support from jest but it's definitely not what I want since it generates a lot of ugly boilerplate code to make things work.

Thank you for your time